# How do I check if a class is readonly in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Can I write a unit test that make sure that a readonly class I write (a class which has no setters) remains readonly in the future? I do not want that anyone to add a setter property in my classes.

Basically, how do I check if a class is has no setters in C#?

Comment: when you say "has no setters" do you mean none of the properties on it have setters?  what about public writable fields?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a way to determine if your class is IMMUTABLE through having no writable properties or fields.  drop all that value type crap from your question.  it's misleading.

Answer (score 5):

*Note: asker originally posed the question "How do I determine if a class is a Value Type?" and later changed it.*

```
bool isValueType = object.GetType().IsValueType
```

or

```
bool isValueType = typeof(YourClass).IsValueType
```

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isvaluetype.aspx

Comment: I am referring to value type pattern.. I want to test if a class has no setters... I do not want to know if it is a struct or other language specific value type such as int...

Answer (score 3):

This should come up zero:

```
var setterCount =  
    (from s in typeof(IDataCollector).GetProperties(
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    where s.CanWrite == true
    select s)
    .Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the key phrase here is "*I do not want that anyone to add a setter property in my classes.*"

In general, if you want to write an immutable class, you should mark your class as [sealed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx) and mark all fields as [readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx).

---

Of course, if you expect people to inherit from your class, you have to consider the following:

- There's nothing preventing a person from inheriting from adding whatever properties they want to your class. You can't enforce that constraint on inheritors, except by convention.
- You *can* do a runtime check using reflection to see if inheritors have added any fields, however I wouldn't recommend it since it violates some of the elementary principles of encapsulation.
- You have to check for more than just setters in your class. Its wholly possible for a person to write a method like `setSomething` (a Java-style setter), or writing methods with side-effects that mutate internal values. There's no efficient way to check if your inheritors haven't used similar trickery to sneak mutability in your classes.

There's really nothing you can do to keep your class readonly if you allow people to inherit your class.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Type type = typeof(YourClass);
    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance);
    bool passesTest = true;
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        passesTest = passesTest && property.CanWrite;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just marking all the fields *readonly*?

Comment: I assume the poster was concerned about derived classes adding mutable fields.

Comment: Because he expressed his concern that the class "remains readonly in the future."  It seems to me that the most plausible scenario in which some other programmer might make the class mutable "accidentally" would be to derive from it and add mutable fields.