# Checking if an instance of an Object is read-only

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, object, reflection, readonly

If I have an instance of an Object, how do I check whether or not it is read only?

I've scoured through System.Type and that are plenty of `IsXxxx()` and `GetXxxx()` types of functions but no `IsReadOnly()`, `IsWriteable()`, `GetReadWriteProperty()`, or anything along those lines. I guess something like `myObj.GetType().IsReadOnly()` would've been too easy, and the Object class itself has nothing useful in it other than GetType().

When I google this question all I get are ways to use the readonly keyword.

I thought of using Reflection and GetProperty() but this is a base class that exists in a List<>, I would need the instance of this object to be a lone property in another object for me to do this I would think.

Any ideas?

Comment: Guess I need to refine my search terms better next time, I believe this question may be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481883/how-do-i-check-if-a-class-is-readonly-in-c

Comment: Can you provide an example of an object that you consider to be readonly? At the object level no such concept is defined. The fields may or may not be readonly, and the properties may or may not have public sets, and it may or may not be marked `[ImmutableObject(true)]` - but... at least 2 of those *don't actually make it immutable*, and the third (the fields) is not compulsory or overly common (since the fields would be private)

Comment: @Marc Gravell: PropertyInfo for a Type gives a CanRead and CanWrite, I was looking for a way to get those on any given object.

Comment: by  .GetType().GetProperties ?

Comment: @MarcGravell: I seem to be confused. If I do `myObj.GetType().GetProperties` I will be getting the properties within `myObj`, not the CanRead/CanWrite of `myObj` itself.

Comment: yes, because there **is no such thing** as an object being CanRead/CanWrite. That concept does not exist.

Comment: So you're saying that you cannot get PropertyInfo on a System.Object? If you can get PropertyInfo on a System.Object then that PropertyInfo will have the CanRead and CanWrite booleans on it.

Comment: An object isn't a property; it is an object. No there is not any such CanRead/CanWrite definition for an object.

Comment: I have properties in various classes that have base types of System.Object and also have CanRead\CanWrite values, as far as I am aware. Maybe I am not understanding how Object works (my background is in C++), or the information reflection provides on types with Object base types.

Comment: while the **properties** might have a CanRead/CanWrite, that says **nothing** about the object that the property returns; multiple properties could return the same object, or an object might not be accessible from **any** properties... please let me know if I'm misunderstanding the question you are asking.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Well, for example when I get the PropertyInfo on a type that has classes within it that have object as their base types, I get the CanRead/CanWrite for all of those. So essentially I'm getting a CanRead/CanWrite on objects, by using PropertyInfo, right? Anyway, I'm sure you're correct, I just need to spend some more time with Reflection so I can better understand it. I have a game engine that I want users in the editor to be able to click on an entity and get current information about it, so I'm trying to recurse through the entire entity and display all of its info.

Comment: `PropertyInfo`s represent properties. Not nested types; not sub-types; not base-types. You are presumably looking at the properties, but that **is not** the objects. There is no concept of CanRead/CanWrite on either an object or a Type

Comment: Maybe we're confusing terms here. In OOP, if `Bar` derives from `Foo` it is still considered to be a `Foo`. So in my example, if something derives from `Object`, is it not then an Object? And if I understand correctly, properties are members of a class, so are we not talking about properties that are also objects?

Comment: Properties are not objects, no. A property just a term for a few methods with a specific pattern, i.e. get_SomeProp and set_SomeProp. So no: properties are not objects. At runtime, if you invoke a property getter it might *return* something that is an object, and via reflection you can inspect the PropertyInfo which represents the definition/declaration of the property (and which is an ojbect). But: nothing more than that. CanWrite here is really just: "is a set accessor defined" - but that has nothing to do with any objects.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I think I finally understand. Thank you for your patience, and help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such concept as an *object* being read-only. A *variable* can be read-only, but that's a different matter. For example:

```
class Foo
{
    private readonly StringBuilder readOnlyBuilder;
    private StringBuilder writableBuilder;

    public Foo()
    {
        readOnlyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        writableBuilder = readOnlyBuilder;
    }
}
```

Here there's only one `StringBuilder` object, but two fields - one read-only and one writable.

If you're asking whether a *type* is immutable (e.g. `string` is immutable, `StringBuilder` isn't) that's a thornier question... there are many different *kinds* of immutability. See [Eric Lippert's blog post on the matter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx) for more details.

Comment: @Vijay Eric has posted, with his intentions to investigate - I think that should be fairly definitive; also - if you're asking people to look at something (which is a bit of an imposition), at least phrase it as a favour rather than a requirement/demand

Comment: @Vijay: I'm not a Microsoft employee, or on the C# team in any way. I've posted an answer though - I'm pretty sure it *is* a bug, and there's a way of provoking particularly nasty behaviour. I agree with Marc though, "your attention is needed" and "pls make yourself available" are rather more like demands than is really called for.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check for ReadOnly fields, Use the `IsInitOnly` property on the FieldInfo class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.isinitonly.aspx

```
//Get the Type and FieldInfo.
Type myType = typeof(myReadOnlyfield);
FieldInfo myFieldInfo = myType.GetField("ReadOnlyfield",
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

//Check if the field is read only
bool readOnly = myFieldInfo.IsInitOnly;
```

Answer (score 2):

Jon Skeet is right (of course), there is no such thing as a read-only object in C#. However, some framework, such as WPF have their own concept of read-only objects. WPF has [freezables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.aspx), objects which can be made immutable at runtime, you can check whether a freezable is frozen via `IsFrozen`.